# Is it possible to use INTENT instead of STRING as List Title in Google Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

#### Some Background:

I use [Lists](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list) a lot for a Google Action with a [NodeJS fulfillment](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/index.html) backend. The Action is primarily Voice-based. The reason for using List is that I can encode information in List's key and use it later to make a decision. Another reason is that Google Assistant will try to fuzzy match the user's input with the Title of the List's items to find the closest matched option. This is where thing's get a bit hard for me. Consider the following example:

```
{
    JSON.stringify(SOME_OBJECT): {
        title: 'Yes'
    },
    JSON.stringify(ANOTHER_OBJECT): {
        title: 'No'
    }
}
```

Now if I say **Yes** / **No**, I can get the user's choice and do something with information stored as stringified JSON in the choice's Key.

But, the users may say **Sure** or **Yup** or **OK** as they basically mean the same thing as saying **Yes**. But as those words don't match **Yes**, Google Assistant will ignore the "**Yes**" option. But all of these words belong to the **smalltalk.confirmation.yes** built-in intent. So, if I could use this intent instead of hardcoding the string **Yes** then I would be able to capture all of the inputs that mean **Yes**.

---

I know I could do this with a **Synonyms** list or **Confirmation** intent. But they also have some problems.

Using Synonyms would require me finding every word which is similar. Besides, I would also need to localize these synonyms to all the supported language.

With Confirmation intent, I won't be able to show some information to the user before asking them to choose an option. Besides, it also doesn't support encoding the options as I can do in List's key.

So, List is a good choice for me in this case.

---

So, is there any way to leverage the built-in intents for this purpose? What do you do in this situation?

Comment: I have done similar things, with list and confirmation intent. But I want to understand what is the problem you are trying to solve I mean what you are facing when are you using list and confirmation built-in intent? I would suggest follow to this approach,  That is what I have found on many articles for such scenario.

Comment: So in your case you just want to have a Yes/No? Can you just put your object data into session storage with `conv.data`?

Comment: @nick I can put the data in session storage. But the problem is I will use this scenario in multiple places. So being able to use a list would be much more easier for me handle than that approach

Comment: It may seem a bit easier in one regard, but does have the tradeoff of impacting the natural language processing.

Comment: It does. That's why I was looking for it. I have already written quite a bit of code using this flow so it would be difficult moving to a different flow.